# Grouping hierarchical data dynimacally

Tags: sql-server-2012, aggregate-functions, hierarchical-data, dynamic-sql

I have the following table structure:

```
ID Criteria01 Criteria02 Criteria03 ... CriteriaN Score
```

and need to create a procedure that returns aggregated score results by hierarchical criteria.

For example, if the criteria is

```
Criteria01 -> Criteria03 -> ID
```

I need to return the data in the following hierarchical format:

```
Criteria03 Score 
           Criteria01 Score
                     ID Score
```

or if I have the following sample data:

[image]

the result will be:

[image]

*Explanations:*

(hierarchical level 1) Calculating average score for each value in Criteria01 or

```
SELECT [Criteria01]
      ,AVG([SCORE])
FROM DataSource
GROUP BY [Criteria01]
```

(hierarchical level 2) Calculating average score for each value in Criteria03 or

```
SELECT [Criteria03]
      ,AVG([SCORE])
FROM DataSource
GROUP BY [Criteria03]
```

(hierarchical level 3) Showing the score by ID.

The above display how the calculations are done. And what is left is to match the ID rows to its parent Criteria03 rows, and then to match the Criteria03 rows to its parent (Criteria01) rows.

So, I can have different hierarchical criteria and need to return result with a hierarchical level column.

Please, note I am not looking and not need a working solution for the sample data I have provided, as I in my real case the things are a litle bit more complicated.

What I am looking for is advice or idea for a good approach of doing this from someone who has been already in such situation.

Comment: I keep staring at your data there and have no clue how you went from the source to the expected results. Could you take another swipe at explaining the expected logic?

Comment: @billinkc I have added some explanations of how calculations are made. I hope it makes more sense now.